# Имеет ли глагол "кончить" исключительно непристойное значение?

Tags: значение-слов, глаголы

В последнее время в русском языке глагол "кончить" всё чаще употребляется в значении "извергнуть сперму при эякуляции", на порносайтах это слово очень широко распространено и нередко безопасный поиск в поисковиках Google, Яндекс срабатывает при попытке осуществить поиск по таким словам. Почему так вышло, что глагол "кончить" имеет в основном непристойное значение? Есть ли вероятность попасть в неловкую ситуацию, употребляя глагол "кончить"?

Comment: Феминистки могут не согласиться с вашими формулировками, и будут правы. Потому что слово "кончить" не привязывается к какому-либо конкретному полу и применяется просто в значении "испытать оргазм". Соответственно, женщины могу "кончать" точно так же, как и мужчины, и им совершенно не обязательно при этом что-либо извергать.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, представители образованных классов обоих полов употребляют этот глагол *в узком доверительном кругу* без ненужных стеснений и стыда: со временем это слово вошло в разряд *коитуса, секса, полового члена* и т.п. Наоборот, малообразованные и грубияны употребляют его, **невзирая на присутствие противоположного пола, жены или мужа, своего интимного партнёра (-ши) и посторонних**, что равносильно отборному мату в присутствии детей и женщин: *Я её так отодрал, что она на ногах не стояла* и т.п. Само слово *отодрать* гораздо более приемлемо, чем *вы+++ть*, но обстановка, "контекст" могут сделать его неприемлемым.
Вы не попадёте в неловкую ситуацию, если скажете "*кончай*!" своему другу/подруге, подразумевая *"хватит тебе препираться, спорить, раздувать конфликт", "болтать лишнее"* и т.п.
То, что вы задались таким вопросом, говорит о том, что вы надёжно застрахованы - помните лишь о вышеописанном ограничении.
В.С.Елистратов приводит такой пример употребления:
**Кончил, не кончил - у вас три минуты** - *шутл*. об ограниченности времени, о необходимости скорее закончить какое-либо дело, поручение. Двойственность подтекста здесь очевидна. Если вы услышите такое в общении с глазу на глаз, то обижаться нечего. Если же присутствуют третьи лица, то вам будет видней.